# NullPointerException called indirectly by SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My Android application crashes when I try to call MyCursorAdapter.bindView. Here is the LogCat log:

```
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at com.mohit.gtodo.TasksCursorAdapter.bindView(TasksCursorAdapter.java:28)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-10 15:22:57.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(463):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the bindView method in my CursorAdapter:

```
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    EditText body = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
    TextView created = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.created);

    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
    title.setSelected(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_COMPLETED)) > 0);
    body.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
    created.setText(((Long)cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_CREATED))).toString());
```

Line 28 starts with `body.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksDBAdapter.Key_BODY)));`
Any other information needed?

**UPDATE**:

```
EditText body = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
```

Seems to be null? Here is the widget:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/body" android:layout_below="@+id/body_txt" android:text="" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minLines="10"></EditText>
```

Comment: You have quite a few method into one another. Have you tried debugging to see which part is null?

Comment: Where/how is 'view' instantiated?

Comment: @Aurora: it should be the view from the bindView because the logcat says that the exception is thrown from bindView and getView is from CursorAdapter.

Comment: Dumb question : is the EditText in the row layout ?

Comment: @fedj: No. Its part of my edit activity.

Comment: The view passed into bindView is the row layout, if you call v.findViewById, it will try to find the view in the row layout, not the full layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get your reference from another view that the view parameter in bindView method.
The view is just the row layout and not the whole layout.
That's why when you do view.findViewById, it returns null because Android doesn't know about this id in this view.